# How to remove the last element from a slice?

Tags: go

I've seen people say just create a new slice by appending the old one

```
*slc = append(*slc[:item], *slc[item+1:]...)
```

but what if you want to remove the last element in the slice?

If you try to replace `i` (the last element) with `i+1`, it returns an out of bounds error since there is no `i+1`.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

You can use `len()` to find the length and re-slice using the index before the last element:

```
if len(slice) > 0 {
    slice = slice[:len(slice)-1]
}
```

<kbd>[Click here to see it in the playground](http://play.golang.org/p/q6a5P379T4)</kbd>

Comment: See I would have though it would have been `slice[:1]`, why is that wrong? :(

Comment: I would have expected slice[:1] to remove the last element

Comment: @OlegzandrDenman [The documentation discusses](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/7) low and high bounds though. `slice[:1]` wouldn't be "1 index away from the end" ... its 1 as the high bound of a range.

Comment: May I mention that the use of <kbd> tags for a [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/) link is rather elegant

Comment: Note. This could produce so much garbage.

Comment: When push and pop are too clean

Answer (score 26):

**TL;DR:**

```
myslice = myslice[:len(myslice) - 1]
```

*This will fail if `myslice` is zero sized.*

**Longer answer:**

Slices are data structures that point to an underlying array and operations like slicing a slice use the same underlying array.

That means that if you slice a slice, the new slice will still be pointing to the same data as the original slice.

By doing the above, the last element will still be in the array, but you won't be able to reference it anymore.

If you reslice the slice to its original length you'll be able to reference the last object

If you have a really big slice and you want to also prune the underlying array to save memory, you probably wanna use "copy" to create a new slice with a smaller underlying array and let the old big slice get garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the popped value, then:

```
mySlice := []int{0, 1, 2, 3}

poppedValue := mySlice[len(mySlice)-1]

mySlice = mySlice[:len(mySlice)-1]
```

and return `poppedValue`.

https://go.dev/play/p/cnZyj0J3daj